# Enable HTTP2 in Local IIS for CSS Preload

Tags: iis, optimization, http2, preload, lighthouse

I am analyzing my E-Commerce website with Lighthouse Dev tool in Chrome. It suggests me to Preload some CSS files as to Eliminate Render-blocking resources.

Why is to link CSS using below code:

`<link rel="preload" as="style" href="Styles/site.css" />`

instead of using:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/site.css" />`

But when i update my code, page doesn't load and i get a warning in the console:

The resource **http://..../Styles/site.css** was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate 'as' value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to chrome. Unused preloads in Chrome will trigger a console warning ~3 seconds after on load. This happens when the resource isn't being consumed (e.g you're not trying to use a script you've preloaded) in a timely manner.

If the resource is needed for the current navigation & will be used, go for preload. If the resource is needed beyond that (and you're not using in the current nav), I'd go for prefetch.

you could refer this below link for more detail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis